# При записи данных в базу данных запись дублируется Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет. В скрипт приходит webhook с другого сервера:

```
$_REQUEST = Json::decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $data = file_get_contents($url . $_REQUEST['ID']);
    $model = Orders::findOne(['data_id' => $data['id']]);
    if($model === null) {
      $model = new Orders();
      $model->data_id = $data['id'];
    }
    $model->test = $data['test'];
    $model->save();
```

Вот такой у меня код. И почему то создается два Заказа (`Orders`) c одинаковым data_id.
В логах вижу что между входящим запросом 3 миллисекунды.
Как можно сделать так чтобы data_id не дублировалось?

Comment: пробовал добавить ``sleep(3);`` но безрезультатно

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил вопрос с помощью `unique` в модели.

```
public function rules()
  {
    return [
      //...//
      ['data_id', 'unique'],
      //...//
    ];
  }
```

**UPD 06.02.2024**

Способ выше так же не помог. Не знаю в чем конкретно была проблема, но решил не напрямую записывать в таблицу Orders из вебхука, а записать сначала в таблицу orders2 к примеру и уже оттуда записывать в orders с проверкой на дубликаты.